# MongoDB remove objects from nested arrays based up on the condition using aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation

**I have a nested array, I have to remove the one object , based upon the condition using aggregation**

here is the JSON I get from mongodb

```json
{
  "_id":  "633d275ceb34a28755974032",
  "name": "free",
  "products": [
    {
      "title": "Product 1",
      "phone": [
        {
          "title": "Best Phone 1 ",
          "video": {
            "Location": "https://video.mp4"
          },
          "freePreview": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Product 2",
      "phone": [
        {
          "title": "Best Phone 2",
          "video": {
            "Location": "https://video.mp4"
          },
          "freePreview": false
        }
      ]
    }
    
  ] 
}
```

But I need the data like

```json
{
  "_id":  "633d275ceb34a28755974032",
  "name": "free",
  "products": [
    {
      "title": "Product 1",
      "phone": [
        {
          "title": "Best Phone 1 ",
          "video": {
            "Location": "https://video.mp4"
          },
          "freePreview": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Product 2",
      "phone": [
        {
          "title": "Best Phone 2",
          "freePreview": false
        }
      ]
    }
    
  ] 
}
```

**In this data *"video object"* is removed inside the phone array , because of freePreview is false,**

> Based upon the freePreview condition , help me to remove the video object

Comment: Do you want to _delete_ the data from the document in the collection or just not have it turned in the results?  Either way, `$map` is probably going to be helpful here

Comment: I just need a result like db.collection.findOne() using aggregation, can you help me in implement, please share a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to iterate through your array of arrays and use [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) along with `$$REMOVE` to remove value conditionally:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            products: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$products",
                    as: "p",
                    in: {
                        title: "$$p.title",
                        phone: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$p.phone",
                                in: {
                                    title: "$$this.title",
                                    freePreview: "$$this.freePreview",
                                    video: {
                                        $cond: {
                                            if: {
                                                $eq: [
                                                    false,
                                                    "$$this.freePreview"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            then: "$$REMOVE",
                                            else: "$$this.video"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJ_zIFKXmLf)

[Here's](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields) a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

[@mickl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73975483/1409374) works great.  If you want to allow for possible document/schema changes, then rather than specifying the fields to keep explicitly, you could use [`"$mergeObjects"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to keep everything and then only modify what you need.

Borrowing heavily from @mickl, here's how you could do that.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      products: {
        $map: {
          input: "$products",
          as: "p",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$p",
              {
                phone: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$p.phone",
                    in: {
                      "$mergeObjects": [
                        {
                          "$arrayToObject": {
                            "$filter": {
                              "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$this"},
                              "as": "kv",
                              "cond": {"$ne": ["$$kv.k", "video"]}
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          video: {
                            $cond: {
                              if: {
                                $eq: [
                                  false,
                                  "$$this.freePreview"
                                ]
                              },
                              then: "$$REMOVE",
                              else: "$$this.video"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lW_h1MXupK3).